# App Logo not displayed in Toast Message Android 12 Tv Leanback App

Tags: android, android-toast, android-12

I am trying to show the message using toast but app logo seems to be missed while displayed. I have  mentioned

```
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

in Android Manifest in application tag but still no luck.

Can any one share Android Toast in android 12 tv walkthrough or sample.[image]

Comment: Since that is controlled by the device, perhaps Android TV in general or your device manufacturer is not showing the icon. Are you testing on actual hardware or an emulator? Also, is your `targetSdk` version 31 or higher?

Comment: targetSdk is above 31, it is tested on real device. For one of the app it is showing app logo but not for my app. App logo to be displayed is not controlled by device.